# Will an online minority student PhD recruitment platform be valuable in the US?

Tags: phd, professorship, recruiting

I know many faculty are concerned about diversity in their labs and it seems to be an ongoing issue. Will it ease PhD recruitment pains to have a searchable database of propsective applicants? Especially for minority applIcants. Not so much to manage the application process but just to find good fit and increase diversity in the group/lab. 
My advisor prides herself in building a diverse lab and went through a significant amount of effort to find right persons in the direct applicant pool that fit her criteria. 
Anyone have any experience with efforts to diversify their labs that proved successful? Will a secure searchable repository of minority applicants make it easier?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a discussion topic and/or survey, not a concretely answerable question.

Comment: By the way, most US universities have online job application systems so my guess is that they'd be more likely to adapt those systems for PhD applications than use a separate piece of software.

Comment: Your edit made a drastic change of the question. The original question is about an online PhD recruitment platform. Now, it's about pain points of PhD recruitment. In my opinion, the new version is even broader than the original.

Comment: Really? Ok. Will make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed literally thousands of posts asking " I study X. This is my GPA, GRE and TOEFL scores. I have published a few papers. I have good recommendation letters. What is my chance getting into US PhD programs?" type of questions on this site, I would say such a central online platform is definitely useful.

In particular, I think it would be very helpful for the students to get an idea what the schools are looking for. Publishing lab openings is a good start. Some schools may be reluctant to publish their requirements in the first place. But, if many schools are doing that, many others will follow suits.

However, I am not too sure if those admission committee members will spend so much time to go through hundreds of thousands (or even more) applicants' files.
My other concerns is the information security. There would be a lot sensitive data to be looked at. So, I think to put students' data on that site may not be a good idea at the moment.

Comment: To support part of the warning here: for maths there is a central site in the US for most postdoc and junior professor positions. It makes life easier for applicants and referees, but means the number of applicants per job is stupidly high.